# Load values when asked

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following code that loads the html with values. Now, it loads at the beginning. But, How can I make it load just when I call the function. And I am also going to send an index so I can send variables dynamically. How can I make it work on this code?

```
var app = angular.module("delivcard", []);
app.controller("DelivCtrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.cards = [{name: 'California Ale Yeast', ferment:'68F - 73F', tolerance: 'High', attenuation: yeastBank[1].attenuation},
  {name: 'California Ale Yeast', ferment:'68F - 73F', tolerance: 'High', attenuation: '73.0% - 80.0%'}];

}]);
```

I am trying to load it from a regular javascript file but it gives undefined $scope.

```
function initShopDisplay()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < yeastBank.length; i++)
    {
        if(yeastBank[i].isPrivate == false)
        {
$scope.card();
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is simple just put that code in the function just like below.

```
var app = angular.module("delivcard", []);
app.controller("DelivCtrl", ['$scope', function ($scope) {

 $scope.card = function ()
{
  $scope.cards = [{name: 'California Ale Yeast', ferment:'68F - 73F', tolerance: 'High', attenuation: yeastBank[1].attenuation},
  {name: 'California Ale Yeast', ferment:'68F - 73F', tolerance: 'High', attenuation: '73.0% - 80.0%'}];
}
}]);
```

call the function where you want to `$scope.card();` or you can call it in html by `ng-click =card();`

Comment: How is can i add more values on the variable dynamically? So, if I have 3 indixes I have three different {data}

Comment: can you please elaborate in detail?.

Comment: I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
    at store.js:124

Answer (score 0):

You can first set `$scope.cards=""` then write a function

```
var app = angular.module("delivcard", []);
app.controller("DelivCtrl", function ($scope) {

$scope.cards = "";
$scope.card = function ()
{
  $scope.cards = [{name: 'California Ale Yeast', ferment:'68F - 73F', tolerance: 'High', attenuation: yeastBank[1].attenuation},
{name: 'California Ale Yeast', ferment:'68F - 73F', tolerance: 'High', attenuation: '73.0% - 80.0%'}];
}
});
```

So in the beginning you wont get undefined error if you call that even while initializing. This will happen in old browsers offen.

Comment: Still got the error. I added some info of where I am calling the variable

Comment: Can you add still more detailed snippet so that its easy to identify.